# How can I estimate growth of function?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, curve-fitting, estimation

Assume that I have this information:

```
   N   seconds

  216      0.00
 1296      0.48
 7776     89.73
46656  16480.96
```

How can I estimate growth of this function??

What is the empirical order-of-growth?

How can I estimate empirical order-of-growth?

Any help will be appreciate!

Comment: Why not put it in a spreadsheet and generate a graph ? You'd already have an idea of the nature of it (linear? exponential?). Once you get the quality, go for the quantity : find one approaching formula for it (possibly using a spreadsheet again, like libre office or gnumeric for instance). But generally you mostly care about the nature of it (also see big-O notation).

Comment: If you know the function's code, you can analyze it to find out its complexity. If you don't, you can try coming up with a non-linear regression model. There's a lot of software that can come in handy. Excel, R-studio, Statistica, to name a few apps.

Comment: Get some more data points. I plotted this and while it's obviously not linear, it's not obvious yet what it *is*.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Maths.

Comment: [wikipedia has an explanation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analysis_of_algorithms#Empirical_orders_of_growth): calculate `log(t2/t1) / log(n2/n1)`. Your first line is useless (can't divide by zero), but for the next three lines we get the two intervals as ~ n^2.92 and ~ n^2.91. So it's a steady n^2.9, give or take.

Answer (score 1):

Plotting the data is a good start; if you plot it on linear scales and also on log scales, you may be able to distinguish a polynomial-growth function from an exponential-growth function.

For quick estimates of order of complexity, compute ratios of time increase.  From the command

```
dc -e '46656 7776/ 16480.96 89.73/  7776 1296/ 89.73 0.48/f'
```

which outputs

```
186
6
183
6
```

or the python command

```
python -c 'print 46656/7776, 16481/90, 7776/1296, 90/0.48'
```

which outputs

```
6 183 6 187.5
```

one sees that as the problem size increases by a factor of six, the execution time increases by a factor of over 180, empirically suggesting an O(n³) complexity.  (An *[empirical](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/empirical#Adjective)* finding is one based on observations rather than theory.  Fitting a curve to a black-box function, where you have no process information, merely knowledge of inputs and outputs, is empirical.)

More generally, a *[multiple regression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_regression)* package may be used to study possible curve-fitting functions.  Suppose *x* is an input, and *y = f(x)* an observed output.  The idea in multiple regression is to compute additional input values, such as *x², x³, ln x, x·(ln x),* etc and then find the best fit for *y* that is a linear combination of the input values.

As a crude approximation, one can also write a program that calculates ratios *y/g(x)* for various functions *g* and for each *x,y* value pair.  Here's an example of this technique applied to the data shown in the question:

```
import math
Ns=(216,1296,7776,46656)
times=(0.00,0.48,89.73,16480.96)
for x,y in zip(Ns,times):
    print '{:5} {:8.2f} {:8.2} {:10.3} {:10.3} {:10.3} {:10.3}'.format(x, y, y/x, y/x**2, y/x**3, y/(x**2.92), y/(x**2 * math.log(x)**8))
```

which produces

```
  216     0.00      0.0        0.0        0.0        0.0        0.0
 1296     0.48  0.00037   2.86e-07   2.21e-10   3.91e-10   4.11e-14
 7776    89.73    0.012   1.48e-06   1.91e-10   3.91e-10   3.58e-14
46656 16480.96     0.35   7.57e-06   1.62e-10   3.84e-10   4.24e-14
```

The last two functions in the above python program, ie *g(x)=x<sup>2.92</sup>* and  *g(x)=x²·(ln x)⁸*, are included to illustrate that you can test fairly complicated functions.  But note that this technique is somewhat ad hoc.

Comment: Thank you for helping!
Can you give me a Java or Scala command that estimates the order of complexity?

Comment: The answer is right if we want to estimate theoretical order-of-growth.But what is the empirical order-of-growth?

Comment: I really appreciate your help,but can you use Scala , Java or C to illustrate your example?

Comment: For Java or C, use array declarations like `double Ns={216,1296,7776,46656};` and a loop construct like `for (i=0; i<sizeof(Ns)/(sizeof double); ++i) { x=Ns[i]; y=times[i]; printf("%f5.0 %f8.2 %f10.3 (etc) \n", x, y, y/x, (etc)); }`

Comment: [plotting the data on the `log-log` scale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analysis_of_algorithms#Empirical_orders_of_growth) is the key.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to generate a graph for all the data points you have using any spreadsheet software(like Excel). Plotting `N vs Seconds` will provide you a good estimate of how time(Seconds) increases with increase in input size(N) providing you information regarding if it has linear growth or exponential growth or something else. The requirement here is that you should have enough data points be confident enough about the observed growth.

Now in case you have access to the code of the method you can go through the code and look for its complexity which will is a clear representation of its growth